# Understanding the msghdr structure from sys/socket.h

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming

I'm trying to understand the following members of the `msghdr` structure of the [sys/socket.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/syssocket.h.html) lib.

- `struct iovec *msg_iov         scatter/gather array`
- `void         *msg_control     ancillary data, see below`

It states below:

> Ancillary data consists of a sequence of pairs, each consisting of a cmsghdr structure followed by a data array. The data array contains the ancillary data message, and the cmsghdr structure contains descriptive information that allows an application to correctly parse the data.

---

I'm assuming the `msghdr` struct, contains the protocol-header information? if so... `*msg_iov` is the input/output "vector" of parameters in the request/response? and the `*msg_control` contains the response messages?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`msg_iov` is an array of input/output buffers with length `msg_iovlen`.  Each member of this array contains a pointer to a data buffer and the size of the buffer.  This is where the data to read/write lives.  It allows you to read/write to an array of buffers which are not necessarily in contiguous memory regions.

`msg_control` points to a buffer of size `msg_controllen` that contains additional information about the packet.  To read this field, you first need to declare a `struct cmsghdr *` (let's call it `cmhdr`).  You populate this by calling `CMSG_FIRSTHDR()` the first time, passing it the address of the `msghdr` struct, and `CMSG_NXTHDR()` each subsequent time, passing it the address of the `msghdr` struct and the current value of `cmhdr`.

From the `msg_control`, you can find interesting things like the destination IP of the packet (useful for multicast) and the contents of the TOS/DSCP byte in the IP header (useful for custom congestion control protocols), among others.  In most cases, you'll need to make a `setsockopt` call to enable receiving this data.  In the examples given, the `IP_PKTINFO` and `IP_TOS` options need to be enabled.

See the [cmsg(3) manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/cmsg.3.html) for more details.

The source IP and port, are not in `msg_control`, but are in `msg_name` which expects a pointer to a `struct sockaddr` with length `msg_namelen`.

Here's an example of how to use this:

```
struct msghdr mhdr;
struct iovec iov[1];
struct cmsghdr *cmhdr;
char control[1000];
struct sockaddr_in sin;
char databuf[1500];
unsigned char tos;

mhdr.msg_name = &sin
mhdr.msg_namelen = sizeof(sin);
mhdr.msg_iov = iov;
mhdr.msg_iovlen = 1;
mhdr.msg_control = &control;
mhdr.msg_controllen = sizeof(control);
iov[0].iov_base = databuf;
iov[0].iov_len = sizeof(databuf);
memset(databuf, 0, sizeof(databuf));
if ((*len = recvmsg(sock, &mhdr, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("error on recvmsg");
    exit(1);
} else {
    cmhdr = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&mhdr);
    while (cmhdr) {
        if (cmhdr->cmsg_level == IPPROTO_IP && cmhdr->cmsg_type == IP_TOS) {
            // read the TOS byte in the IP header
            tos = ((unsigned char *)CMSG_DATA(cmhdr))[0];
        }
        cmhdr = CMSG_NXTHDR(&mhdr, cmhdr);
    }
    printf("data read: %s, tos byte = %02X\n", databuf, tos); 
}
```

Comment: why is `struct sockaddr_in`? shouldn't it be `struct sockaddr`?

Comment: `struct sockaddr` is a generic type for getting socket info.  For an IPv4 socket, the specific type is `struct sockaddr_in`.  For a UNIX domain socket, it's `struct sockaddr_un`, and for an IPv6 socket, it's `struct sockaddr_in6`

Comment: Haha okay. Where the hell do you see that though lol? I don't even see in the spec at all.

Comment: `man 7 ip`, `man 7 unix`, and `man 7 ipv6`, as well as `man 7 socket`.

Comment: Ok yea got it now... they really should put that shit in the main spec or at least put it in comments rather than declaring a generic type, because you can't even use that generic type, right?